# golang get kubernetes resources(30000+ configmaps) failed

Tags: go, kubernetes

I want to use client-go to get resources in Kubernetes cluster. Due to a large amount of data, when I get the configmap connection is closed.

```
stream error when reading response body, may be caused by closed connection. Please retry. Original error: stream error: stream ID 695; INTERNAL_ERROR
```

configmaps:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system get cm |wc -l
   35937
```

code:

```
cms, err := client.CoreV1().ConfigMaps(kube-system).List(context.TODO(), v1.ListOptions{})
```

I try to use Limit parameter, I can get some data, but I don’t know how to get all.

```
cms, err := client.CoreV1().ConfigMaps(kube-system).List(context.TODO(), v1.ListOptions{Limit: 1000 })
```

I'm new to Go. Any pointers as to how to go about it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [v1.ListOptions](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1#ListOptions) describes how it works:

> limit is a maximum number of responses to return for a list call. If more items exist, the
>       server will set the `continue` field on the list metadata to a value that can be used with the
>       same initial query to retrieve the next set of results.

This means that you should examine the response, save the value of the `continue` field (as well as the actual results), then reissue the same command but with `continue` set to the just seen value. Repeat until the returned `continue` field is empty (or an error occurs).

See the [API concepts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#retrieving-large-results-sets-in-chunks) page for details on handling chunking of large results.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [ListPager](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/tools/pager#ListPager) to paginate requests that need to query many objects. The ListPager includes buffering pages, so it has improved performance over simply using the Limit and Continue values.

Comment: I don't suppose you have a working example